# Can't use/find the authorization code when using the Spotify API in Java

Tags: java, authentication, spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify API in Java 17 using Gradle.

In the documentation it says the authorization code should be in the redirectURI, but it doesn't work or I can't seem to find it.

I tried the following scripts. These are in the same package.

```
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyApi;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.authorization.authorization_code.AuthorizationCodeUriRequest;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;

public class AuthorizationCodeUriExample {
    private static final String clientId = "<client_id>";
    private static final String clientSecret = "<client_secret>";
    private static final URI redirectUri = SpotifyHttpManager.makeUri("https://example.com/spotify-test-uri");

    private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .build();
    private static final AuthorizationCodeUriRequest authorizationCodeUriRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCodeUri()

            .build();

    public static void authorizationCodeUri_Sync() {
        final URI uri = authorizationCodeUriRequest.execute();

        System.out.println("URI: " + uri.toString());
    }

    public static void authorizationCodeUri_Async() {
        try {
            final CompletableFuture<URI> uriFuture = authorizationCodeUriRequest.executeAsync();

            // Thread free to do other tasks...

            // Example Only. Never block in production code.
            final URI uri = uriFuture.join();

            System.out.println("URI: " + uri.toString());
        } catch (CompletionException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            System.out.println("Async operation cancelled.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        authorizationCodeUri_Sync();
        authorizationCodeUri_Async();
    }
}
```

Note that the client Id and the client secret are censored bc of obvious reasons.

This spits out 2 of the same URLs and they redirected as expected to a domain with the following URL: `https://example.com/spotify-test-uri?code=AQAz1CZeAZqGz2vl3NYf0XES4jrmwsr2JmNRFeMXcOnn5HZ_teOXcQKTKdMdEsnKnmwsEYGFXpB67iND0NDZqsWajOZEx6CEZmF0eV9tNsJZtMfAgT0LlG-S0wrva0OTDjICztePV_DkJy03ci9yRSyw3lO5BMxc6Ye1EiMzXv9nztA0FkiXBg`

I thought the piece behind "code" were to be the authorization code. Correct me if I'm wrong.
I put the authorization code in the following script:

```
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyApi;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.exceptions.SpotifyWebApiException;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.model_objects.credentials.AuthorizationCodeCredentials;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.authorization.authorization_code.AuthorizationCodeRequest;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;

public class AuthorizationCodeExample {
    private static final String clientId = "<client ID>";
    private static final String clientSecret = "<client secret>";
    private static final URI redirectUri = SpotifyHttpManager.makeUri("https://example.com/spotify-test-uri");
    private static final String code = "AQAz1CZeAZqGz2vl3NYf0XES4jrmwsr2JmNRFeMXcOnn5HZ_teOXcQKTKdMdEsnKnmwsEYGFXpB67iND0NDZqsWajOZEx6CEZmF0eV9tNsJZtMfAgT0LlG-S0wrva0OTDjICztePV_DkJy03ci9yRSyw3lO5BMxc6Ye1EiMzXv9nztA0FkiXBg";

    private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .build();
    private static final AuthorizationCodeRequest authorizationCodeRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCode(code)
            .build();

    public static void authorizationCode_Sync() {
        try {
            final AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials = authorizationCodeRequest.execute();

            // Set access and refresh token for further "spotifyApi" object usage
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());

            System.out.println("Expires in: " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getExpiresIn());
        } catch (IOException | SpotifyWebApiException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void authorizationCode_Async() {
        try {
            final CompletableFuture<AuthorizationCodeCredentials> authorizationCodeCredentialsFuture = authorizationCodeRequest.executeAsync();

            // Thread free to do other tasks...

            // Example Only. Never block in production code.
            final AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials = authorizationCodeCredentialsFuture.join();

            // Set access and refresh token for further "spotifyApi" object usage
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());

            System.out.println("Expires in: " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getExpiresIn());
        } catch (CompletionException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            System.out.println("Async operation cancelled.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        authorizationCode_Sync();
        authorizationCode_Async();
    }
}
```

This outputs:
`Expires in: 3600 Error: Invalid authorization code`
instead of a refresh code.

The interesting thing is that it does know when it expires.

I probably forgot something obvious as I'm not that experienced. Anyone who knows what I missed/a possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of the [authorization code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization) or at the [example implementation](https://github.com/spotify-web-api-java/spotify-web-api-java/blob/develop/examples/authorization/authorization_code/AuthorizationCodeExample.java)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).